# Postman app is opening instead of google chrome

Tags: postman

I've installed Postman app in chrome apps. Now, whenever i click on chrome icon, postman opens default instead of chrome. This is very tedious and I've to click on chrome app launcher to open chrome every time. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you're on Ubuntu but this worked for me:

edit ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Postman
Icon=google-chrome
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id={gobbledigook}
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Google-chrome
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

remove `--app-id={gobbledigook}` from the Exec line, save, and then try again